# Generate a vector with elements that contain a fixed number of unique values

Tags: matlab, indexing, unique, sorting

Suppose I have a vector 
A =

```
 3     5     3     3     2     2     4     2     6
```

I need to produce a new vector B that will contain all these values from the beggining vector A that will result in a unique number of n elements (suppose n=3, for the purpose of this example). The new vector should be B =

```
 3     5     3     3     2
```

since up to the fifth element of vector A we have 3 unique values(3,5,2).
Actual vectors are a lot larger, so I would rather need a general solution and preferably by avoiding a loop. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) for this problem. However, be sure to use the `'stable'` option.

```
A = [3     5     3     3     2     2     4     2     6]; 
n = 3; 

[x, id] = unique(A,'stable'); 

B = A(1:id(3))
```

This results in

```
B =

     3     5     3     3     2
```

Comment: The 'stable' option is not recognized in Matlab R2009a.

Comment: @R.Schifini: The option has been introduced in R2012a. Your solution works for earlier releases as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
A = [3  5  3  3  2  2  4  2  6];
n = 3;

[b,i] = unique(A,'first');
h = sort(i);
A(1:h(n))
```